# Kdenlive freezing

Tags: video-editor, kdenlive

I started a project and it was going fine. Then I wanted to add an effect to an item on the timeline. I clicked on the item, and kdenlive just froze. I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save previous changes if possible, then restarted my computer.

Now when I open the project, it goes slow for a while. Then when I try clicking anywhere on the timeline and pressing play, the preview just remains blank. The backup files aren't loading either. When I try opening even the oldest kdenlive completely freezes and I have to either force it shut or restart the computer.

Any idea how I can recover my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently opening older backups directly works.

Backups are stored in ~/.local/share/kdenlive/.backup/